# Let $\{a_n\}^\infty_{n=1}$ be a sequence of positive real number such that $\sum ^{\infty}_{n=1} a_n$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\{a_n\}^\infty_{n=1}$ be a sequence of positive real number such that $\sum ^{\infty}_{n=1} a_n$  is convergent . Which of the following are convergent correct?
$$1. \sum ^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$$

$$2. \sum ^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{a_n^\frac{1}{4}}{n^\frac{4}{5}}$$

$$3. \sum ^{\infty}_{n=1} na_n\sin(\frac{1}{n})$$

1 is true beacuse $\lim _{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ is convergent

i dont how to processed for 2 and 3

Comment: Perhaps, "because".

Comment: @suresh. Was it a past NBHM question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1)

From convergence we have that $a_n \to 0 \Rightarrow \exists n_0 \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $a_n<1 ,\forall n \geq n_0$

Thus $1+a_n>1 \Rightarrow \frac{a_n}{1+a_n} \leq a_n ,\forall n \geq n_0$

From this we can conclude that $\sum_n \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ converges.

For 2)

Use Holder inequality for $p=\frac{5}{4}$ and $q=4$ and you will conclude that the given sum converges.

But use the exponent $q=4$  for  $\frac{1}{n^{\frac{4}{5}}}$ and also use the fact that if $\sum_na_n$ converges then $\sum_na_n^p$  also converges for $p>1$ and $a_n>0 \forall n \in \Bbb{N}$

Thus 2) is correct.

For 3)

Use the fact that $|\sin{x}| \leq |x| \Rightarrow na_n\sin{\frac{1}{n}} \leq a_n$ and then the comparison test gives the conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

3) is good: The formula $|\sin u|\leq|u|$, so $n\sin(1/n)\leq 1$ and hence $\displaystyle\sum na_{n}\sin(1/n)\leq\sum a_{n}<\infty$.

Comment: ..what about (2) can you tell me my idea correct for 1

Comment: Someone else posted the answer for 2). Your idea for 1) does not go through. The convergence of the tail fails to tell anything about the convergence of the series.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use limit comparison test $x_n=a_n$ and $y_n=\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$. Hence convergent.
2. Use Holder's inequality $p=4,q=\frac{4}{3}$ then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_n^{\frac{1}{4}}}{n^{\frac{4}{5}}}\le (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n)^{\frac{1}{4}}(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^{\frac{16}{15}})^{\frac{3}{4}}$. hence converges.

3 Use limit comparison test $x_n=a_n$ and $y_n={na_n}{\sin(\frac{1}{n})}. $Hence convergent.

Answer (score 1):

**For 1**

simply note that $\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}\leq a_n$

Comment: Your second claim is actually false. Take for example $a_{n} = \frac{1}{2n\, \log^{2}(2n)}$

Comment: @TheOscillator you're right, any idea to fix it?

Comment: Well, In my opinion it screams for an application of Holder's inequality.

Comment: @TheOscillator but isn't it your $a_n$ is a counter example to show that 2 is false?